# When using arcpy can I only calculate fields of a subtype and not the entire feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I'm appending two sepearte shapefiles into one feature class with different subtypes.  Is there a way to only calculate fields from a certain subtype?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your main question of if it is possible to calculate fields from a certain subtype; there are two main functions that could be used to interrogate what field type a column is in a feature class. `arcpy.Describe` used on a field object or `arcpy.ListFields` used on a feature class ([see ESRI documentation here about field object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004n000000)).

One way you could then solve your problem would be to create a function like this and return a list of field names of that type:

```
    def GetFieldNamesOfType(fc, fieldType):
        returnFieldNames = []
        fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
        for field in fields:
            if field.type == fieldType:
                returnFieldNames.append(field.name)
        return returnFieldNames
```

If I understand the end goal of what you want to accomplish correctly… The returning list of field names could be used to limit a [Search Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) (as the fields argument) to get the values from each feature class matching the field type of interest. These values could then in turn be used in an [Insert Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) for the new merged feature class.